# Object is not getting returned instead main array return

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am facing an issue while returning an object from the array using map function .

I have an array of object which looks like

```
const data={
"Sessions" : 
[{"id" : "2", "Name":{"firstName": "jonas", "lastName":"parker"}}
, {"id" : "3", "Name":{"firstName": "peter", "lastName":"donl"}}, {"Id": 
1,"Name":{"firstName": "xyz", "lastName":"abc"}}]}
```

Now, I am trying to return the object

```
const active = data?.Sessions ?? [].map((session) => {({label: 
    `${session.Name.firstName}`, value: `${session.Name.lastName}`}))
```

So, I was expecting it return an array of object which will have label and name as keys and their respective values.

So, I am getting the `data?.Sessions` array in return i.e. original array of object which I am using for iterating.

Can any one help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: your `data` array syntax isn't correct. Please provide correct array

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array#map` on data.sessions. You are currently using the null coalescing operator so that map is only called if sessions is not null or undefined, and on an empty array, at that.

```
const active = data?.Sessions.map((session) => ({label: `${session.Name.firstName}`, value: `${session.Name.lastName}`}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in your active variable.

That means the active variable will get the left hand side value, `data?.Sessions` because it is not null or undefined.

Also, you are iterating the over an empty array: `[].map` on the right hand side of the assignment.

Try this:

````js
const active = data?.Sessions.map(function(session){
    return {
            label: session.Name.firstName, 
            value: session.Name.lastName
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array of label and value:

```js
const data={
"Sessions" : 
[{"id" : "2", "Name":{"firstName": "jonas", "lastName":"parker"}}
, {"id" : "3", "Name":{"firstName": "peter", "lastName":"donl"}}, {"Id": 1,"Name":{"firstName": "xyz", "lastName":"abc"}}]}

let active = (data?.Sessions ?? []).map((session) => ({label: session.Name.firstName, value: session.Name.lastName})
)

console.log(active)
```